# Changing iptables chain from port based to ip based

Tags: iptables, xen

Im working to limit access to a new **XenServer 6.2** installation. The default iptables rules on the boxes have a `RH-Firewall-1-INPUT` chain that exposes quite a bit to the outside world.

Without going through and adding `-s <ip range>` to each rule (there are many) is there a way to add the ip ranges to all the rules by default?

Historically I build iptables with INPUT DROP and FORWARD DROP then open everything to the internal networks followed by a `-j REJECT` to ignore the rest. The **XenServer** rules seem a bit more complex and having an inadvertant *iptables lock-out* would be a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.  Off the top of my head, it's been a while since I used iptables but.

```
# Create a whitelist chain
iptables -N whitelist

# Add some ip's to it
iptables -A whitelist -s 1.2.3.4/32 -j RETURN
iptables -A whitelist -s 2.3.4.5/32 -j RETURN
iptables -A whitelist -s 3.4.5.6/32 -j RETURN
# etc

# default drop on whitelist, no match - drop
iptables -P whitelist DROP


# Jump to the whitelist chain by default which will jump back if we get a match
iptables -A INPUT -j whitelist

# now back at your input chain
# All the normal rules follow
```

Comment: Silly question: do I need the additional rules after the 'whitelist'? If iptables has rejected anyone that doesn't match do I need the limits afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a rule that will `-j JUMP` to another chain, if the IP matches your range, else just drop everything.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, these are the default XenServer 6.2 rules - basically the stock RedHat rules since XenServer is based on RedHat:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     47   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 499M 1226G RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 187M packets, 1105G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 312K  429M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
15842 1331K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255 
    0     0 ACCEPT     esp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     ah   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:631 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  xenapi *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:67 
 497M 1223G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:694 
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
    3   180 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80 
10474  543K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:443 
1883K 2404M REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

So if you want to limit the access to a known range (eg `192.168.0.0/24`) you could do something like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s ! 192.168.0.0/24 -j REJECT
```

This will reject anything NOT from that source address, so the remaining rules will only apply to that source range.

If you have multiple trusted sources, you'll need to use a new chain like @Matt said (although you should use `-j RETURN` instead of `-j INPUT`)